# creating array based list with <E>

Tags: java, arrays, object, stack

I'm creating an array based stack class in java, but I'm also forced to use the class

```
public class MyStack<E> implements Stack<E>.
```

My pop and peek are also in form of public E pop()/ public E peek().

I can't figure out how to use  formats and create an array.

The size of array has to be 128, and I tried setting

```
private E[] Stack = new Object[128]
```

but it gives bunch of warnings and I can't search how to deal with this Object type. I tried using it by typecasting (int) or (char) each time I use item in the stack, but I'm getting a ClassCastException. For example, I tried using `(int) tmp = (int)MyStack.pop();` and am getting the ClassCastException when I use the Object type.

Can anyone help me understand how this Stack, or  works (or give a directing link to some well-written explanation) or tell me anywhere else I'm misguided?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: I read through the link, and I think that answers most of my question, although I still don't understand how to solve the ClassCastException issue.  I'll have to look up for that. Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `java.util.Stack`, which is a class and not an interface, the code would be:

`public class MyStack extends Stack<TypeName>`